# Show that $\sqrt3 \notin K$, when $K =\{a + b\sqrt2 \mid a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I think this is a Tower Law question, but I don't really know where to start!

Please could somebody walk me through it!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, $a,b\neq 0,$ such that $\sqrt{3}=a+b\sqrt{2}$, then we would have that 
$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(a+b\sqrt{2})=a^2+2ab\sqrt{2}+2b^2=3$$
This would imply that
$$ \sqrt{2}=\frac{3-a^2-2b^2}{2ab}$$
which cannot hold since $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$, so $\sqrt{3}\notin K$

Comment: thank you so much, that is so so helpful

Comment: you're welcome @LaurenM

Comment: It’s be easier to note that $a^2+2ab\sqrt{2}+2b^2=3$ implies $a^2+2b^2=3$ and $ab=0$.