# If $K=\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, find $[K ∶\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[K(\sqrt3) ∶\mathbb{Q}]$.

Tags: group-theory, extension-field

I'm new to the subject and struggling to understand the steps when finding the degree of a field extension, I've been finding the minimal polynomial and then using the degree of that as the answer, but here, I'm not sure how to do it

Please could somebody talk me through the steps!
It's very very much appreciated

Comment: Please don’t force extra spaces in formulas. MathJax knows how to space most things correctly.

Comment: You were told about an hour ago how to see that $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $K$. That should tell you how to find $[K(\sqrt{3}):K]$. And finding a primitive element for $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should also be pretty clear. Then you can use the tower law you thought was involved [an hour ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675545/show-that-sqrt3-notin-k-when-k-a-b-sqrt2-mid-a-b-in-mathbbq) but wasn’t.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [degree of a field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension) has some examples very similar to these. Have you seen that?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So sorry! I assumed this was somewhere I could post while I'm struggling, I'm sure I can find the answer somewhere else! I am not very smart but I'm trying to learn. I don't think this platform probably is the place for me to ask for help! Things that are 'very clear' to some people aren't to others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[K ∶\mathbb{Q}]$ is the  dimension of the vector space $K$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}.$  I will make you understand via basis. A basis of $K$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}.$  So the dimension is 2. 
Now $[K (\sqrt{3})∶\mathbb{Q}]=[K(\sqrt{3})∶K].[K∶\mathbb{Q}]$. Can you complete?

Comment: Thank you so so much!! So helpful

Comment: you are welcome.